# How to combine two closest rows into one row based on the created timestamp

Tags: sql

I have the following sql 2008 table.

```
ID  RefundId    RefundStatusId          CreatedOn
334 549         3                   2011-10-12 12:04:37.773
333 549         1                   2011-10-12 12:04:20.390
332 549         6                   2011-10-12 12:03:05.990
```

Any query can give me a result like:

```
RefundCheckId   StatusId             PreviousStatusId           CreatedOn
    549             3                    1                        2011-10-12 12:04:37.773
    549             1                    6                        2011-10-12 12:04:20.390
    549             6                    null                     2011-10-12 12:03:05.990
```

**Solution below : Updated based on Marco's answer.**

```
SELECT t.RefundId AS RefundCheckId, t.RefundStatusId AS StatusId,
  (SELECT TOP 1 RefundStatusId FROM table
   WHERE RefundId = t.RefundId AND CreatedOn < t.CreatedOn
   ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC) AS PreviousStatusId, t.CreatedOn
FROM table t
WHERE t.RefundId = 549
ORDER BY t.CreatedOn DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

### MySql version

```
SELECT t.RefundId AS RefundCheckId, t.RefundStatusId AS StatusId,
  (SELECT RefundStatusId FROM your_table 
   WHERE ID < t.ID
   ORDER BY ID DESC
   LIMIT 1) AS PreviousStatusId, t.CreatedOn
FROM your_table t
ORDER BY t.ID DESC
```

### MS-SQL version

```
SELECT t.RefundId AS RefundCheckId, t.RefundStatusId AS StatusId,
  (SELECT TOP 1 RefundStatusId FROM your_table 
   WHERE ID < t.ID
   ORDER BY ID DESC) AS PreviousStatusId, t.CreatedOn
FROM your_table t
ORDER BY t.ID DESC
```

Comment: I believe this is SQL Server 2008, LIMIT does not apply

Comment: @Adrian: I edited my post to insert MS-SQL version. Thanks a lot for your suggestion

Comment: @Adrian: anyway when users tag their question as _sql_ I never know which database they are using... it's a problem...

Comment: I know, right? However, the text implies it "SQL 2008". 1up'ed your answer anyway

Comment: @Adrian: ooops, I didn't read it on question text... my fault

Comment: Thanks. It does give me the result which I wanted.